# How to configure applications in ami 4

Tags: amazon-emr, amazon-ami

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/API_Application.html) says

> In Amazon EMR releases 4.0 and greater, the only accepted parameter is
>   the application name. To pass arguments to applications, you supply a
>   configuration for each application.

But I cannot find an example that shows how to pass arguments in ami 4. All I can find are examples configuring exports such as below. I am trying to figure out how to set the version of Spark to use.

```
[ 
      { 
         "Classification":"hadoop-env",
         "Properties":{ 

         },
         "Configurations":[ 
            { 
               "Classification":"export",
               "Properties":{ 
                  "HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST":"true",
                  "HADOOP_CLASSPATH":"/path/to/my.jar"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set an arbitrary version of Spark to use like you could with 3.x AMI versions. Rather, the version of Spark (and other apps, of course) is determined by the release label. For example, the latest release is currently emr-5.2.1, which includes Spark 2.0.2. If you want a 1.x version of Spark, the latest version available is Spark 1.6.3 on release emr-4.8.3.